# Getting entries from database where there are more than one entry in a corresponding database with a shared ID (prepared statement)

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, mysqli, prepared-statement

this is going to be a bit complicated. But I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do.

I've got a table in a database as follows:

Table - Entries

```
ID | User | Address | Workflow | Audit Date |
1  | Tim  | 123     | 10 p/w   |  22/2/2013 |
2  | Bob  | 222     | 20 p/w   |  22/2/2013 |
```

Now in a corresponding table i have pictures:

Table - Pictures

```
ID | JobNo | User | ImagePath | ImageName |
52 | 1     | Tim  | /1.jpg    | /2.jpg    |
53 | 1     | Tim  | /3.jpg    | /4.jpg    |
```

Now Pictures.Jobno corresponds to Entries.ID

Alright so what I'm after, is to list all entries from table Entries when the related jobNo has more than 2 image entries. if it has 1 or less, I want to ignore the listing.

So at the moment I can call entries like this through php:

```
    function getAllEntries() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!($query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Entries
                                    ORDER BY Date DESC"))) {
     echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
    if (!$query->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $query->errno . ") " . $query->error;
}
    $query->bind_result($ID, $User, $Address, $Workflow, $Audit);
    while ($query->fetch()) {
        //Echo each entry here
    }
    $query->close();
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

My issue is, how do I then incorporate what I want to do? I want to say:

Select all entries, where in table Pictures there are 2 or more images corresponding to the job number/id comparison in the Entries table.

I'm sure this doable. But I can't think of the sql statement or how to bind it in a prepared statement correctly

SELECT * FROM Entries, Pictures, Where Pictures.Jobno = ID.Entries AND (row amount in pictures) >= 2.

Or something? Is this just an SQL problem? Or do I need an if statement and to run a separate SQL query.

I'm self taught with php and sql I'm afraid - so I don't quite know how to resolve this myself.

Comment: You can just use an `left join` on entries and pictures for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to handle this is typically by joining against a subquery which retrieves the number of Pictures per `JobNo` and filtering those `>= 2` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
  entries.*, 
  numpics
FROM entries 
LEFT JOIN (
  /* Subquery joined returns aggregate COUNT() in pictures per JobNo */
  SELECT JobNo, COUNT(*) AS numpics FROM pictures GROUP BY JobNo
) pcounts ON entries.ID = pcounts.JobNo
HAVING numpics >= 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/347f4/8

Because of MySQL's lenient treatment of the `GROUP BY`, you can probably get away with just a `LEFT JOIN`, against `pictures` without the subquery:

```
/* MySQL Only */
SELECT entries.*
FROM
  entries 
  LEFT JOIN pictures ON entries.ID = Pictures.JobNo
GROUP BY entries.ID
HAVING COUNT(pictures.JobNo) >= 2
```

Comment: Oh, I learnt something new today :) Thank you. The resolves my problem. Have to wait 2 minutes before I can select your answer. Thanks!